# how to remove Duplicate meta for each page breaks in joomla?

Tags: seo, joomla-3.5

google crawler found many Duplicate meta descriptions and title tags in my web, like these :

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی?showall=&limitstart=

/tag/طراحی-دکوراسیون-مغازه/687-طراحی-داخلی-گل-فروشی?showall=1

Obviously the crawler found each page breaks as same meta or title tag!!!
how can i fix this?

my joomla version is 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

These pages would appear to be generated by the tags component, which are paginated lists of articles.

Each individual tag can have separate meta data if you create a `tagged items` menu item for each one, though sub-pages within each tag can not have their own meta data.

Whilst it should technically be possible to write a plug-in to achieve this, it would seem a mistake since it does actually make sense that they share meta data between list pages.  This is because the purpose of each page is exactly the same - ie to list articles that match that specific tag.  There is no logical change of description to individualise these beyond possibly "page x of...".

It is also possible for users to be able to switch between amounts shown per-page, so the page shown to the user may not always be the same as the one in Google.

Google's guidelines on paginated content are here: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

They do say that doing nothing is an option:

> Leave whatever you have exactly as-is. Paginated content exists
>   throughout the web and we’ll continue to strive to give searchers the
>   best result, regardless of the page’s rel=”next”/rel=”prev” HTML
>   markup—or lack thereof.

If you want to add the `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` tags, these can be overriden in your template.  An example of a pagination override in action can be seen in the core Protostar template under templates/protostar/html/pagination.php

You could possible also set the first page as canonical, again with an override.

Ultimately, I wouldn't worry about listings pages - beyond helping Google crawl your site, they don't have any major SEO benefit.  It's the actual article pages that need to be listed correctly.